# Why is there java.io.FileNotFoundException when I use HttpURLConnection to get data via api?

Tags: java, android, api, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

Please help ~

There is DailyForeignExchangeRates opendata on
https://openapi.taifex.com.tw/v1/DailyForeignExchangeRates

When I browse it from chrome, I will get a file as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnGLm.png)

But when I using HttpURLConnection to get data in Android Studio,
I always get FileNotFoundException. Why ?

```
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://openapi.taifex.com.tw/v1/DailyForeignExchangeRates
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.weberhwang.testfirebase.MainActivity.lambda$catchData$0(MainActivity.java:115)
W/System.err:     at com.weberhwang.testfirebase.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Below is my code

[AndroidManifest.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.weberhwang.testfirebase">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TestFireBase">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[MainActivity.java]

```
package com.weberhwang.testfirebase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.weberhwang.testfirebase.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private TextView textViewResult;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        catchData();
    }

    private void catchData() {
        String catchData = "https://openapi.taifex.com.tw/v1/DailyForeignExchangeRates";
        new Thread(()->{
            try {
                URL url = new URL(catchData);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = in.readLine();
                StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
                while (line != null) {
                    json.append(line);
                    line = in.readLine();
                }
                Log.d("MyLog",json.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try using "FileOutputStream" since the URL response is file.

Comment: I have tried to use FileOutputStream to process, but found that the problem may be with https authentication. Anyway, thank you very much.